# Ошибка terraform - missing virtio device virtio0

Tags: proxmox, terraform

Выдает ошибку при деплое
есть конфиг терраформа

Error: missing virtio device virtio0
│
│   with module.servers.proxmox_virtual_environment_vm.vm["vm-bmu.staging.fun-box.ru"],
│   on modules/proxmox-config/virtual_machines.tf line 9, in resource "proxmox_virtual_environment_vm" "vm":
│    9: resource "proxmox_virtual_environment_vm" "vm" {